# ubuntu-tweak not starting

Tags: 14.04, gnome, ubuntu-tweak

When I try to run ubuntu-tweak in terminal I get the following:

`adwaita@adwaita-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ ubuntu-tweak`

`Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked`

`Aborted`

`adwaita@adwaita-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ ubuntu-tweak -d`

`[Launcher][DEBUG] Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty`

`Application: Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.8-1~trusty1`

`Desktop:gnome (ubuntu-tweak:84)`

`Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked`

`Aborted`

`adwaita@adwaita-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$`

What to do now? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are also experiencing a bug that has been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/1376530).

Installing `libglib2.0 and libgtk2.0` has solved the problem for some.

Comment: A fix has been released and you should upgrade the package using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Installing libglib2.0 and libgtk2.0 didn't solved it.

Comment: trying to upgrade not much data balance